# C++ - class issue

Tags: c++, class, pointers

At: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/82-classes-and-class-members/

There is the following program (I made some small modifications):

```
#include <iostream>

class Employee
{
public:
    char m_strName[25];
    int m_id;
    double m_wage;

    //set the employee information
    void setInfo(char *strName,int id,double wage)
    {
        strncpy(m_strName,strName,25);
        m_id=id;
        m_wage=wage;
    }

    //print employee information to the screen
    void print()
    {
        std::cout<<"Name: "<<m_strName<<"id: "<<m_id<<"wage: $"<<wage<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    //declare employee
    Employee abder;
    abder.setInfo("Abder-Rahman",123,400);
    abder.print();
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile it, I get the following:

[image]

And, why is a pointer used here? `void setInfo(char *strName,int id,double wage)`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

```
strncpy(m_strName,strName,25);
```

You need to `#include <cstring>` (where strncpy is declared).

2.

```
std::cout<<"Name: "<<m_strName<<"id: "<<m_id<<"wage: $"<<wage<<std::endl;
```

should be

```
std::cout<<"Name: "<<m_strName<<"id: "<<m_id<<"wage: $"<<m_wage<<std::endl;
```

3.

```
void setInfo(char *strName,int id,double wage)
```

can be set to

```
void setInfo(const char *strName,int id,double wage)
```

to get rid of the g++ 4.x.x warning.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right, but, why this warning? And, why did we have to insert "const" to gt rid of it? Thanks.

Comment: With `abder.setInfo("Abder-Rahman",123,400);`, you're passing in a constant string, but you declared `void setInfo(char *strName,int id,double wage)` as `char *`, which indicates to the compiler that you may wish to modify `strName`.  The compiler can see that you can't do that, so it is trying to be helpful.  Listen to warnings; they almost always help you write more robust code.

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to include the header that declares the `strncpy` function. So add

```
#include <cstring>
```

at the beginning.

And the member name is `m_wage` but you've used it as `wage` in your `print` member function.

Change

```
std::cout<<"Name: "<<m_strName<<"id: "<<m_id<<"wage: $"<<wage<<std::endl;
```

to

```
std::cout<<"Name: "<<m_strName<<"id: "<<m_id<<"wage: $"<<m_wage<<std::endl;
                                                         ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
#include <string.h>
```

And change wage to m_wage on line 19.

Comment: Please don’t mix C++ and C headers.

Answer (score 1):

You need :

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
```

Comment: Please don’t mix C++ and C headers.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the last warning/error message - the first parameter of the `setInfo()` member function should be declared as `const char*`. Plain `char*` represents pointer to a *mutable* character array, which string literal `"Abder-Rahman"` isn't.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because strncpy is declared in the cstring header file.

A pointer is used because you are working with C strings, which are char arrays. Arrays in C are used through pointers. And strncpy takes two pointers to char(char arrays) to do the copy process.

Comment: "Please don’t mix C++ and C headers." – Konrad Rudolph :)

Comment: thanks for your reply. When you say:"Arrays in C are used through pointers", how then are arrays used in C+=? Thanks.

Comment: @SWEngineer It applies the same to c++, i wanted to emphasize the difference with other languages.