# Arrays in C are used through pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

In a question I posted here: [C++ - class issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768310/c-class-issue)

One of the replies, which was from @SanSS mentioned the following part of the reply:

**Arrays in C are used through pointers...**

How is this done? And, can you clarify this by an example if possible?

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a more general "What are pointers" question. There are many answers worth reading here. If they do not cover your answer could you refine your question?

Comment: Arrays in C **are** pointers. There are many Q/As on SO and Google to help you out here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is meant by that could be a couple of things:

1) the subscript operator is defined in terms of pointer arithmetic. C99 6.5.2.1/2 "Array subscripting" says:

> The definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2))).

As an example, assume you have an array declated like so: `char s[] = "012345";`

All of the following evaluate to '4':

- `s[4]`
- `*(s + 4)`
- `4[s]` - this
  unusual construct might surprise you,
  but because of the way that
  subscripting is defined by the
  standard, this is equivalent to `*(4 +
  s)`, which is the same as `*(s + 4)`
  and the same as `s[4]`.

2) (closely related to the above) array names evaluate to pointers to the first element of the array in most expressions (being the operand to the `sizeof` operation being the main exception).